# Add the row count as a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

If I have a complicated query that generates a bunch of rows, how would I, using SQL, add a new column that contains the amount of rows, in every cell?

For example, if my complicated query results with this:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3
a           b           c
d           e           f
g           h           i
j           k           l
```

I want the fourth column to contain the amount of rows (in this case 4):

```
Col1        Col2        Col3    Amount
a           b           c       4
d           e           f       4
g           h           i       4
j           k           l       4
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Subquery?   I know it would work in SQL Server.

Comment: Looks like you would have to run the query twice (once regular, once as a subquery) Perhaps you'd do better if we understood WHY you want to do this.  I'm not sure what possible advantage it can give you to put the total into its own column.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the following:

```
SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c, (select count(*) from a)
FROM a
```

Where a is your big query you were talking about and a.a, a.b, and a.c are all the columns of that query. There is probably a better answer, but this should work, and seems relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE) AS Amount
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Should give you what you're after.

Comment: Here's my query: http://pastebin.com/wgqFBY14
I get the error #1146 - Table 'stuffbyd_forum.a' doesn't exist